# Query url in a json object

Tags: arrays, json, url

I have a data.json file with the following format:

```
    {
      "accounts": [
        {
          "quantity": "200",
          "prodType": "stock",
          "symbol": "LOL",
          "side": "Buy",
          "status": "Completed",
          "prodDesc": "Εθνική τράπεζα",
          "market": "Greece",
          "averageCost": "131,16",
          "totalCost": "123,47",
          "lastPrice": "121,123",
          "value": "123,34",
          "positionPercentage": "10",
          "valueEUR": "113,23",
          "pl": "1300",
          "plPercentage": "12",
          "plEuro": "1238",
          "results": "12-01-2017",
          "dividend": "12-03-2017",
          "isin": "1234566"
        },...
      ]
}
```

I want to extract the accounts which have side=Buy. So i make my request as following:
http://localhost:3004/accounts?side=Buy but it did not work. The accounts is a json array as you can see. How can i restruct my query url to work?

Comment: have you written any code to parse JSON

Comment: what is your attempt ?

Comment: There is no magic involved in JSON, the query parameters parsing does not depends on the JSON output, but on the server that handles your request.

Comment: I want to submit to filter parameters using react and redux. i create a db.json file using json server. My default url is localhost:3000/account-list. I make the "fake" rest call: const response = yield call(authorizedRequest, 'get', '/me/accounts'); To make my filtering request im writing: onst response = yield call(authorizedRequest, 'get', `me/accounts/${action.payload.side}&${action.payload.status}`);

Comment: Please, provide more informations on what you have done so far, what stack you are using, etc **in your question**. For now, it is totally unclear.

Comment: I want to make a request to a json server using two parameters. The call to fetch the default data is const response = yield call(authorizedRequest, 'get', '/me/accounts');. Now, i want to make a call for fetching the data that has side = Buy. Should i change the url format to make this? Or do i have to create some fuctions to implement the desired "filtering"?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this on the server side as response of your api

```
  var response =  accounts.map(function(a){ 
  if(a.side == 'buy'){
    return a;
  }
});
 return response;
```